# What are the exact differences between ERD and RDF

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, erd

Could someone explain me the exact differences between an ERD model, where we speak about entities, relations and attributes, and RDF, where we speak about subject, predicate, and object?
I've checked various resources such as http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/RDFnot.html, but the superiority of one over the other is still not clear to me.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a question of superiority, it's just about which is the best fit for your problem.

Both are useful.

RDF is best when you have graph structures to represent, or when you need interchange with many other systems over which you have no control.

Comment: Aren't changes great you will always face systems you will have to exchange information with other systems and thus loosing control. And since both are equally simple, why wouldn't I be choosing for the RDF format? I just try to wrap my mind.

Answer (score 3):

ERD is well-suited for structured data modelling. So if your problem involves using of semi-structured content, ERD shortly becomes a mess. Another difference is that ERD is mainly used in closed database design where you can force client applications to use defined schema, on the other hand RDF is oriented to solve open world problems where are no strict schema or term conventions and information tends to be public and scattered.